# service error while reading from spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-api

I am writing an Adwords Script from where I am trying to repeatedly read values from spreadhseets and I end up with the following error :

Service Error : Spreadsheets

The code is :

```
//Running the WRITER script
scriptText = processor_scripts_sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
eval(scriptText);
var script = eval( 'new reading(\"' + processor + '\")');
script.main();
  //Running the READER script


 scriptText = processor_scripts_sheet.getRange(2,3).getValue(); --> PROBLEM HAPPENS HERE
eval(scriptText);
script = eval( 'new writing(\"' + processor + '\")');
script.main();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but in case someone has this or similar issue here's what I did.
I had similar issue when running .getValue() on a Range.
I found that a different range in the script had values read that were out of bounds.
Strangely, the .getValue() function on this Range did not fail.
I passed the bad values through a loop, which also did not fail:

```
for(i = 0; i<nonValues.length; ++i){
       var callIndex = ArrayLib.find(**BADVALUES**,0,nonValues[i][0]); //-1 = nothing found
       if (callIndex != -1){
         nonReport.getRange((callIndex+5),12).copyTo(nonSheet.getRange((i+2),13),{contentsOnly:true});
         nonReport.getRange((callIndex+5),13).copyTo(nonSheet.getRange((i+2),14),{contentsOnly:true});
       }    
   }     

    var etaRange = nonSheet.getRange(2,11,nonRows,11);
    var etaValues = etaRange.getValues()<---FAILS HERE!
```

So the point I suppose, with GAS if you read the execution transcript, the line that fails may not be the issue, it may be a block previous to the last line that runs.

I hope that is helpful for someone at least.